# How to create ActorSystem for Remote in akka without using application.conf file in Java?

Tags: java, akka

Currently, I am using `application.conf` file to create remote actor system. My code is like :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("RemoteActor1", ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("RemoteActor1"));
    ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(Props.create(ActorSlave1.class), "RemoteActorProcessor1");
}
```

And my application.conf file is

```
RemoteActor1{
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    netty.tcp {
        hostname = "IN1WXL-300897"
        port=2561
    }
  }
  }
}
```

I don't want to include this `application.conf` file in my code. How to ingone it and configure remote actor system from code only ?

Comment: See the answer linked above for configuring an `ActorSystem` from code. If you're happy with the `application.conf` configuration format but just don't want to include it in your code/jar, you can load it from the filesystem by passing a `config.file` system property to the JVM as documented at https://github.com/typesafehub/config